# Facebook Pixel Microdata not detected on route change of Angular 7 App

Tags: angular, facebook, microdata, facebook-pixel

We have setup Facebook pixel to pull in our website products to a Facebook Product Catalogue. A requirement for this is to add the microdata to our website application product page - which we have done.

The issue is everything works perfectly when I load a new browser window and go directly to a product page, the microdata is detected and the product is added to our Facebook Catalogue.

But when I start on our homepage and navigate to a product page the microdata is not automatically detected. See the screenshots

Navigating to a product:
[image: the microdata is not detected in Facebook Pixel Helper]

Reloading the same product page and the microdata is detected in Facebook Pixel Helper:
[image: the microdata IS detected]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? We use google tag manager to add the fb pixel script and fire the related events.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GTM, you should beware of the fire event type you choose for your tag. You can use a custom fire event, or you can manually fire the pageview event. Use the preview mode to watch wich fire event are fired.

Personally, I send custom gtag for each page type in my resolvers:

```
declare var gtag;

if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    gtag({
        'event' => 'pageView',
        'type' => 'productPage',
    });
}
```

Then you can configure this custom fire event in GTM back office.